# hive sql aggregate

Tags: sql, group-by, hive

I have two tables in Hive, `t1` and `t2`

```
>describe t1;
>date_id    string

>describe t2;
>messageid string,
 createddate string,
 userid int

> select * from t1 limit 3;        
> 2011-01-01 00:00:00 
  2011-01-02 00:00:00 
  2011-01-03 00:00:00 

> select * from t2 limit 3;
87211389    2011-01-03 23:57:01 13864753
87211656    2011-01-03 23:57:59 13864769
87211746    2011-01-03 23:58:25 13864785
```

What I want is to count previous three-day distinct userid for a given date.
For example, for date `2011-01-03`, I want to count distinct userid from `2011-01-01` to `2011-01-03`.
for date `2011-01-04`, I want to count distinct userid from `2011-01-02` to `2011-01-04`

I wrote the following query. But it does not return three-day result. It returns distinct userid per day instead.

```
SELECT to_date(t1.date_id), count(distinct t2.userid) FROM t1 JOIN t2 
ON (to_date(t2.createddate) = to_date(t1.date_id))  
WHERE date_sub(to_date(t2.createddate),0) > date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 3) 
AND to_date(t2.createddate) <= to_date(t1.date_id) 
GROUP by to_date(t1.date_id);

`to_date()` and `date_sub()` are date function in Hive.
```

That said, the following part does not take effect.

```
WHERE date_sub(to_date(t2.createddate),0) > date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 3) 
AND to_date(t2.createddate) <= to_date(t1.date_id)
```

EDIT: One solution can be (but it is super slow):

```
SELECT to_date(t3.date_id), count(distinct t3.userid) FROM
(
 SELECT * FROM t1  LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
 WHERE 
 (date_sub(to_date(t2.createddate),0) > date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 3)
  AND to_date(t2.createddate) <= to_date(t1.date_id)
 )
) t3 
GROUP by to_date(t3.date_id);
```

UPDATE: Thanks for all answers. They are good.
But Hive is a bit different from SQL. Unfortunately, they cannot use in HIVE.
My current solution is to use `UNION ALL`.

```
 SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (to_date(t1.date_id) = to_date(t2.createddate))
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (to_date(t1.date_id) = date_add(to_date(t2.createddate), 1)
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (to_date(t1.date_id) = date_add(to_date(t2.createddate), 2)
```

Then, I do `group by` and `count`. In this way, I can get what I want.
Although it is not elegant, it is much efficient than `cross join`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following should seem to work in standard SQL...

```
SELECT
  to_date(t1.date_id),
  count(distinct t2.userid)
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN
  t2
    ON  to_date(t2.createddate) >= date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 2)
    AND to_date(t2.createddate) <  date_add(to_date(t1.date_id), 1)
GROUP BY
  to_date(t1.date_id)
```

It ***will***, however, be slow.  Because you are storing dates as strings, the using to_date() to convert them to dates.  What this means is that indexes can't be used, and the SQL engine can't do Anything clever to reduce the effort being expended.

As a result, *every possible combination* of rows needs to be compared.  If you have 100 entries in T1 and 10,000 entries in T2, your SQL engine is processing a million combinations.

If you store these values as dates, you don't need `to_date()`.  And if you index the dates, the SQL engine can quickly home in on the range of dates being specified.

NOTE: The format of the `ON` clause means that you *do not* need to round `t2.createddate` down to a daily value.

**EDIT**  Why your code didn't work...

```
SELECT to_date(t1.date_id), count(distinct t2.userid) FROM t1 JOIN t2 
ON (to_date(t2.createddate) = to_date(t1.date_id))  
WHERE date_sub(to_date(t2.createddate),0) > date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 3) 
AND to_date(t2.createddate) <= to_date(t1.date_id) 
GROUP by to_date(t1.date_id);
```

This joins t1 to t2 with an `ON` clause of `(to_date(t2.createddate) = to_date(t1.date_id))`.  As the join is a LEFT OUTER JOIN, the values in `t2.createddate` MUST now *either* be NULL (no matches) or be the same as `t1.date_id`.

The `WHERE` clause allows a much wider range (3 days).  But the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` has already restricted you data down to a single day.

The example I gave above simply takes your `WHERE` clause and put's it in place of the old `ON` clause.

**EDIT**

Hive doesn't allow `<=` and `>=` in the ON clause?  Are you *really* fixed in to using HIVE???

If you really are, what about BETWEEN?

```
SELECT
  to_date(t1.date_id),
  count(distinct t2.userid)
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN
  t2
    ON to_date(t2.createddate) BETWEEN date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 2) AND date_add(to_date(t1.date_id), 1)
GROUP BY
  to_date(t1.date_id)
```

Alternatively, refactor your table of dates to enumerate the dates you want to include...

```
TABLE t1 (calendar_date, inclusive_date) =
{ 2011-01-03, 2011-01-01
  2011-01-03, 2011-01-02
  2011-01-03, 2011-01-03

  2011-01-04, 2011-01-02
  2011-01-04, 2011-01-03
  2011-01-04, 2011-01-04

  2011-01-05, 2011-01-03
  2011-01-05, 2011-01-04
  2011-01-05, 2011-01-05 }

SELECT
  to_date(t1.calendar_date),
  count(distinct t2.userid)
FROM
  t1
LEFT JOIN
  t2
    ON to_date(t2.createddate) = to_date(t1.inclusive_date)
GROUP BY
  to_date(t1.calendar_date)
```

Comment: the issue is Hive does not support `Between AND` in `ON` clause. We can use it on `Where` clause. However, the problem is it is super slow if we only use `where` and do not use `on` in HIVE `JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

You need a subquery:

try something like this (i cannot test because i don't have hive)

```
SELECT to_date(t1.date_id), count(distinct t2.userid) FROM t1 JOIN t2 
ON (to_date(t2.createddate) = to_date(t1.date_id))  
WHERE t2.messageid in 
    (
    select t2.messageid from t2 where 
    date_sub(to_date(t2.createddate),0) > date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 3) 
    AND 
    to_date(t2.createddate) <= to_date(t1.date_id) 
   )
GROUP by to_date(t1.date_id);
```

the key is that with subquery FOR EACH date in t1, the right records are selected in t2.

EDIT:

Forcing subquery in from clause you could try this:

```
SELECT to_date(t1.date_id), count(distinct t2.userid) FROM t1 JOIN 

(select userid, createddate  from t2 where 

    date_sub(to_date(t2.createddate),0) > date_sub(to_date(t1.date_id), 3) 
    AND 
    to_date(t2.createddate) <= to_date(t1.date_id) 
) as t2

ON (to_date(t2.createddate) = to_date(t1.date_id))  

GROUP by to_date(t1.date_id);
```

but don't know if could work.

Comment: Does not work. It cannot be used in Hive. It wants to pass `t1.date_id ` to the subquery. But Hive does not allow.

Answer (score 2):

I am making an assumption that t1 is used to define the 3 day period. I suspect the puzzling approach is due to Hive's shortcomings. 
This allows you to have an arbitrary number of 3 day periods. 
Try the following 2 queries

```
SELECT substring(t1.date_id,1,10), count(distinct t2.userid) 
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 
ON substring(t2.createddate,1,10) >= date_sub(substring(t1.date_id,1,10), 2) 
AND substring(t2.createddate,1,10) <=  substring(t1.date_id,1,10) 
GROUP BY t1.date_id
```

--or--

```
SELECT substring(t1.date_id,1,10), count(distinct t2.userid) 
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 
ON t2.createddate like substring(t1.date_id ,1,10) + '%' 
OR t2.createddate like substring(date_sub(t1.date_id, 1) ,1,10) + '%' 
OR t2.createddate like substring(date_sub(t1.date_id, 2) ,1,10) + '%' 
GROUP BY t1.date_id
```

The latter minimizes the function calls on the t2 table. I am also assuming that t1 is the smaller of the 2. 
substring should return the same result as to_date. According to the documentation, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions, to_date returns a string data type. 
Support for date data types seems minimal but I am not familiar with hive.

Comment: If you only want the period for a single date then this query could be optimised by removing the join. Also if you have populated t1 with a lot of dates then it is not really needed. Just remove the join and specify the period in a WHERE. 
Please explain how the t1 is used if this does not improve performance.

Comment: The first solution has `>=` and `<=` in on clause. It is not allowable in Hive. The second solution, Hive does not support `or` in on clause.